# C++ to Delphi , memcpy and others

Tags: c++, delphi

I am not able to convert, can someone show me the way? : D

```
void getText(char* dst, tField field)
{
    if(field.fieldType > 0xF)
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(handle,(LPCVOID) field.text.ptr,(LPVOID)dst, field.textLength, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy((void*) dst, (void*)field.text.cstring, field.textLength);
    }   
    dst[field.textLength]=0;
}
```

I tried, but not working, is difficult.

```
procedure getText(dst: ShortString; field: tField);
var
  NBR: ULONG_PTR;
begin
  if field.fieldType > $F then
    ReadProcessMemory(tibiaProcess, field.text.ptr, @dst, field.textLength, NBR)
  else
    Move(field.text.cstring[0], dst, field.textLength);

  dst[field.textLength] := #0;
end;
```

tField in Delphi, case is union (C++)

```
type
  tField = record
    textLength: Int8;
    unknown1: String[2];
    fieldType: Int8;
    unknown2: String[2];
    unknown3: Integer;
    case Integer of
      0:
        (ptr: Pointer);
      1:
        (cstring: String[15]);
  end;
```

tField in C++, I'm having trouble with CopyMemory

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct tField
{
    union nameField
    {
        void* ptr;
        char cstring[16];
    } text;
    uint8_t textLength;
    char unknown1[3];
    uint8_t fieldType;
    char unknown2[3];
    uint32_t unknown3;
};
```

procedure, and vNode...

```
vData = record
    a: Int32;
    b: Int8;
    c: Int8;
    unknown2: Int16;
    d: tField;
    e: tField;
    f: Int8;
  end;

  vNode = packed record
    previusNode, nextNode: Pointer;
    unk1: Int64;
    data: vData;
  end;

procedure printList();
var
  length, k: Integer;
  list: array of vNode;
  startingNodeAddress: DWORD;
  nextNodeAddress: Pointer;
  description, name: ShortString;

  NBR1, NBR2, NBR3, NBR4: Cardinal;
begin
  description := '';
  name := '';
  ReadProcessMemory(handle, ptr(LIST_LENGTH), @length, 4, NBR1);
  if (length > 0) then
  begin
    GetMem(Pointer(list), length * SizeOf(vNode));

    ReadProcessMemory(handle, ptr(LIST_BEGIN_PTR),
      @startingNodeAddress, 4, NBR2);
    ReadProcessMemory(handle, ptr(startingNodeAddress + 4),
      @nextNodeAddress, 4, NBR3);

    for k := 0 to length - 1 do
    begin
      ReadProcessMemory(handle, nextNodeAddress, @list[k], SizeOf
          (vNode), NBR4);
      nextNodeAddress := list[k].nextNode;
    end;

    for k := 0 to length - 1 do
    begin
      getText(name, list[k].data.d);
      ShowMessage(String(name));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

C++, i thing is same.

```
struct vNode
{
    void* previousNode;
    void* nextNode;
    uint64_t unknown1;
    struct vData
    {
        uint32_t a;
        uint8_t b;
        uint8_t c;
        uint16_t unknown2;
        tField d;
        tField e;
        uint8_t f;
    } data;
};
void printList()
{   
    uint32_t length;
    vNode* list;
    DWORD startingNodeAddress;
    void* nextNodeAddress;
    int k;
    char description[256];
    char name[256];


    ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPCVOID)(LIST_LENGTH), (LPVOID)&length, 4, NULL);
    if(length>0)
    {
        list=(vNode*)malloc(length * sizeof(vNode));
        ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPCVOID)(LIST_BEGIN_PTR), (LPVOID)&startingNodeAddress, 4, NULL);
        ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPCVOID)(startingNodeAddress+4),&nextNodeAddress, 4, NULL);
        for(k=0;k<length;k++)
        {
            ReadProcessMemory(handle, nextNodeAddress,  (LPVOID)&list[k],  sizeof(vNode),  NULL);
            nextNodeAddress=list[k].nextNode;
        }


        for(k=0;k<length;k++)
        {
            getText(name,list[k].data.d);
            printf("%s", name);
        }
        free(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this: `procedure getText(dst: PChar; field: tField);`, and use `CopyMemory(dst, @field.cstring, field.textLength);`. Keep in mind that I don't know how `TField` is declared.

Comment: Did you remove `@` from the other `dst` too? `ReadProcessMemory(handle, field.ptr, dst, field.textLength, NBR)`.

Comment: Instead of decreeing, "Access Violation" you should supply the missing details.

Comment: Before I continue, please can I ask why you use ShortStrings?

Comment: And also, before we go on, please show the code that calls the routine in question. Specifically the part where you allocate the buffer.

Comment: Your latest code is riddled with errors. From top to bottom. You have answers for the original question. Do you want us to debug your entire program? You are going to need to learn more about programming, and especially about the dangers of casting. Your casting habits are killing you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tField` you define in Delphi does not have the same memory layout as the `tField` defined in the C++ code.

You really need to check the return value of `ReadProcessMemory()` to make sure it is actually reading data at all, and pay attention to the output value of the last parameter to make sure it is reading as many bytes as you requested.

A translation of the original code to Delphi would look more like this:

```
type
  nameField = packed record
    case Integer of
      0: (ptr: Pointer);
      1: (cstring: array[0..15] of AnsiChar);
  end;

  tField = packed record
    text: nameField;
    textLength: Byte;
    unknown1: array[0..2] of AnsiChar;
    fieldType: Byte;
    unknown2: array[0..2] of AnsiChar;
    unknown3: LongWord;
  end;

  vData = record
    a: LongWord;
    b: Byte;
    c: Byte;
    unknown2: Word;
    d: textField;
    e: textField;
    f: Byte;
  end;

  vNode = record
    previousNode: Pointer;
    nextNode: Pointer;
    unknown1: UInt64;
    data: vData;
  end;
  PNodeList = ^vNodeList;
  vNodeList = array[0..MaxInt] of vNode;
```

```
procedure ReadProcMem(addr, dst: Pointer; numBytes: ULONG_PTR);
var
  numBytesRead: ULONG_PTR;
begin
  if not ReadProcessMemory(handle, addr, dst, numBytes, numBytesRead) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  if numBytesRead <> numBytes then
    raise Exception.Create('Not all bytes were read!');
end;

procedure getText(dst: PAnsiChar; field: tField);
begin
  if field.fieldType > 0xF then
    ReadProcMem(field.text.ptr, dst, field.textLength)
  else
    Move(field.text.cstring[0], dst^, field.textLength);

  dst[field.textLength] := #0;
end;

procedure printList;
var
  length: LongWord;
  list: PNodeList;
  startingNodeAddress: DWORD;
  nextNodeAddress: Pointer;
  k: Integer;
  description: array[0..255] of AnsiChar;
  name: array[0..255] of AnsiChar;
begin
  ReadProcMem(Pointer(LIST_LENGTH), @length, 4);
  if length > 0 then
  begin
    GetMem(list, length * SizeOf(vNode));
    try
      ReadProcMem(Pointer(LIST_BEGIN_PTR), @startingNodeAddress, 4);
      ReadProcMem(Pointer(startingNodeAddress+4), @nextNodeAddress, 4);
      for k := 0 to length-1 do
      begin
        ReadProcMem(nextNodeAddress, @(list^[k]), SizeOf(vNode));
        nextNodeAddress := list^[k].nextNode;
      end;

      for k := 0 to length-1 do
      begin
        getText(name, list^[k].data.d);
        Writeln(name);
      end;
    finally
      FreeMem(list);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: dst[field.textLength] := #0; would be cleaner

Comment: I edited the question, I used this procedure you passed and return "Access violation at address 004B34A6 in module 'Project1.exe'. Write of address 004B3689"

Comment: I was avoiding the use of pointer arithmetic, since not all versions of Delphi support it.

Comment: @MrMago: the `tField` you defined in Delphi does not match the layout of the `tField` in the C++ code.

Comment: @Remy All versions do support it for PAnsiChar

Comment: a "literal translation" would not use `nameField` as an explicitly declared named type :-P

Comment: Acess Violation at address 004043bc in module 'Project1.exe'. Write of address 004b36A4.

Comment: @MrMago Why are you quoting error messages to us? What are we going to do with them? We don't have your code. You still won't show us the code that calls this. How do we know that you even allocated any memory? Perhaps you are just writing on a stale pointer. Certainly looks that way? Do you want help or not? If you do, then show all the code that we need. Show an SSCCE.

Comment: @Arioch'The: the original `union` is typed, but inline inside the parent `struct`.  Delphi does not support that particular feature, which is why I broke I out into a separate type declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I'd convert this to a function that returns AnsiString.

```
procedure getText(field: tField): AnsiString;
var
  NBR: DWORD;
begin
  SetLength(Result, field.textLength);
  if (field.fieldType > $F) then
    ReadProcessMemory(handle, field.ptr, Pointer(Result), field.textLength, NBR)
  else
    Move(field.cstring, Pointer(Result)^, field.textLength);
end;
```

There's a proviso. We don't know what TField is. So we've no idea whether or not the use of TField's members is appropriate. Perhaps you translated it poorly. I've no idea what cstring is. I have strong suspicion that its use in Move won't work.

Comment: #pragma pack(1)
struct tField
{
 union nameField
 {
  void* ptr;
  char cstring[16];
 } text;
 uint8_t textLength;
 char unknown1[3];
 uint8_t fieldType;
 char unknown2[3];
 uint32_t unknown3;
};

Comment: Please don't supply detail in comments. Please edit question. You also need to supply Delphi code.